# Lightning Scheduler "Outbound Modify Appointment" Flow: No access to Primary Field

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-scheduler

I am debugging the **Outbound Modify Appointment** Template Flow but I can't access the `Time Slot Screen`:

[image]

It shows a non-intuitive message

> Looks like you don't have access to the Primary field, so you can't schedule a service appointment. Your Salesforce admin can help with that.

[image]

The other **Outbound Flow** works totally fine, but I don't know if there is some field visibility I am missing since I am debugging with an Admin user.

Somebody know where the problem might be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some research copying the parameters from other flows, I just realised that the default flow template made by whoever works at Salesforce Lightning Scheduler didn't populate the variable WorkTypeGroupId on this template, so the component didn't load but gave me a completely stupid useless message with no sense.

Thank you for making me waste 5 hours of my life on this shit...

Answer (score 0):

I think 'IsRequiredResource' is set to false under the Assigned Resource. Please set *IsRequiredResource = true* in Assigned Resource when creating a new Service Appointment.
Hope this fixes the issue.